# Why does window.innerWidth go past my viewport size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to .appendChild() an element into my viewport without introducing vertical/sideways scrolling to my browser window. If I set the x and y values as window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, the element appears outside of my viewport. How can I fix this?

Function for width and height:

```
function XY() {
let x = window.innerWidth;
let y = window.innerHeight;
return [x, y];
}
```

Viewport:
[image]

After appending elements:
[image]

^Notice the addition of vertical and horizontal scroll bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` and `y` in your example will be the first pixel **outside** the viewport, to the bottom right of it. Remember that these values are 0-based.

For instance, suppose `innerWidth` is 5 and `innerHeight` is 3. You'd have:

```
[0, 0]  [1, 0]  [2, 0]  [3, 0]  [4, 0]  [5, 0]
[0, 1]  [1, 1]  [2, 1]  [3, 1]  [4, 1]  [5, 1]
[0, 2]  [1, 2]  [2, 2]  [3, 2]  [4, 2]  [5, 2]
```

With your current code, `[x, y]` would be `[5, 3]`, which would be here:

```
[0, 0]  [1, 0]  [2, 0]  [3, 0]  [4, 0]  [5, 0]
[0, 1]  [1, 1]  [2, 1]  [3, 1]  [4, 1]  [5, 1]
[0, 2]  [1, 2]  [2, 2]  [3, 2]  [4, 2]  [5, 2]
                                                [5, 3]
```

To get the bottom right pixel, you'd want

```
return [window.innerWidth - 1, window.innerHeight - 1];
```

The -1 is because we're talking about a single pixel, which is 1x1. Of course, you'd have to allow for any width and height of the element you're adding. A 10x10 element would need -10 on both.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("msg"));
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "box";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.style.left = (window.innerWidth - div.offsetWidth) + "px";
    div.style.top = (window.innerHeight - div.offsetHeight) + "px";
}, 800);
```

```css
/* Use border-box */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* Full viewport */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Show a grey background */
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* Our box div */
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg">Box will appear in the bottom-right in 800ms...</div>
```